# how make a density plot of the eigenvalues of a symbolic matrix in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a colour plot of the difference of the two first eigenvalues of that matrix. In order to do this, first I have defined a symbolic matrix with two parametters "x" and "y". Then I obtain the eigenvectors and eigenvalues (shorted) and compute the gap beetwen the two first eigenvalues . Finally (and I think that here is the problem...) I make a grid of points X and Y in order to evaluate it with the function "energy_gap(x,y)" storing the result in Z and then using this in order to do the plot, but it doesn't work....Any idea why?

```
import numpy as np
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
from sympy import symbols

x = symbols("x")
y = symbols("y")
matrix = [[x+2, x,y],[y**2,x,3],[y+4,2,1]]

simbolic_matrix = lambdify((x,y), matrix,'numpy')


def eigen_system(x,y):
    values, vectors = numpy.linalg.eig(np.array(simbolic_matrix(x,y)))
    values_short = np.sort(values)
    vectors_short = vectors[:,values.argsort()]
    return  values_short , vectors_short

def energy_gap(x,y):
    values , vectors = eigen_system(x,y)
    gap = abs(values[1])-abs(values[0])
    return gap

def plot_energy_gap():
    x = np.arange(1.1, 3.0, 0.1)
    y = np.arange(1.1, 3.0, 0.1)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = energy_gap(X,Y)
    im = plt.imshow(Z, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu,extent=(1.1,3,1.1,3))  
    plt.colorbar(im)  
    plt.show()

plot_energy_gap()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some extensive testing, I'm afraid I've come to the conclusion that `numpy`s Eigen stuff calculator can operate on a mesh of matrices like you're trying. The best solution I could get was creating the mesh manuaslly:

```
def plot_energy_gap()
    Z = []
    for x in  np.arange(1.1, 3.0, 0.1):
        Z.append([])
        for y in np.arange(1.1, 3.0, 0.1):
            Z[-1].append(energy_gap(x, y))
    im = plt.imshow(Z, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu,extent=(1.1,3,1.1,3))  
    plt.colorbar(im)
```

Maybe someone else can vectorize this. **EDIT** The one line version (forgot it):

```
Z = [[energy_gap(x, y) for y in np.arange(1.1, 3.0, 0.1)] for x in np.arange(1.1, 3.0, 0.1)]]
```